# ubuntu forgets program position

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

After installing Ubuntu 10.04 on an nvidia dualmonitor system there is a weird behavior. Every program starts in the middle of the two dual monitors (overlapping both).

Where can i change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit:] 
This solution is just working for some programs. For example "System\Preferences\About Me" behaves still weird.

== Solution for some programs ==

In the "NVIDIA X Server Settings" tool is the option "Make this the primary display for the X screen"